# I have to post data by AJAX in wordpress to another Website

Tags: ajax, api

I have to post data by AJAX in wordpress to another Website (http://123abc.com/register) .But I always get Error .This is my jquery AJAX code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'fname'              : $('input[name=fname]').val(),
            'lname'              : $('input[name=lname]').val(),
            'email'              : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'password'           : $('input[name=password]').val(),
            'gender'             : $('input[name=gender]').val(),
            'accent'             : $('input[name=accent]').val(),
            'type'               : $('input[name=type]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'http://123abc.com/register', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', 
            encode          : true,
            success: function(data){                
                if(data.error){
                    //show error message here
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors + '</div>');
                }else{
                    //handle success part       
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.message + '</div>');              
                }               
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                //request error 
                $('#name-group').html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);   
              }             
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

Please help.Thanks in ADVANCE

Comment: Please don't embed dead links. Use example.com

Comment: Note that the `success/error/complete` callbacks are [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), use the promise callbacks `done/fail/always` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work due to the "same-origin policy" unless that server you are trying to reach specifically allows these type of requests with something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. You can read the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in order to get more information about this topic.

From my tests, the server will also need another header configured namely the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` so if we combine those two options a valid setup might look like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With
```

Comment: AFTER much google through it , I found that it will be done through REST API. Do you have any idea about how to do that

Comment: @MainakRay You need to send the form data to your WordPress server first (I imagine you are using WordPress since you are posting here) in a JSON format perhaps and then use a tool like [`CURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a `POST` request to that remote server.

Comment: Yes the ajax got connected to another server.thanks @webtoure

Comment: @MainakRay If you don't need the control level that `CURL` offers you can use WordPress's [`HTTP API`](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) more specifically the [`wp_remote_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) function.

Comment: do you know how to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: in the AJAX script so that it can access the server.

Comment: The server you are trying to `POST` to **needs to have that option enabled** and this does **not** depend on your script.

Comment: ok so if the server that i gets to connected need any script or code to add that (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)

Comment: @MainakRay you need configure that into configuration of your server Apache or nginx